# No executor to a Netty pipeline. What happens?

Tags: netty

For example, Floodlight openflow stack uses Netty for it's IO, and it defines following Pipeline factory class.

```
public class OpenflowPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

    protected Controller controller;
    protected ThreadPoolExecutor pipelineExecutor;
    protected Timer timer;
    protected IdleStateHandler idleHandler;
    protected ReadTimeoutHandler readTimeoutHandler;

    public OpenflowPipelineFactory(Controller controller,
                                   ThreadPoolExecutor pipelineExecutor) {
        super();
        this.controller = controller;
        this.pipelineExecutor = pipelineExecutor;
        this.timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
        this.idleHandler = new IdleStateHandler(timer, 20, 25, 0);
        this.readTimeoutHandler = new ReadTimeoutHandler(timer, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        OFChannelState state = new OFChannelState();

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("ofmessagedecoder", new OFMessageDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("ofmessageencoder", new OFMessageEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("idle", idleHandler);
        pipeline.addLast("timeout", readTimeoutHandler);
        pipeline.addLast("handshaketimeout",
                         new HandshakeTimeoutHandler(state, timer, 15));
        if (pipelineExecutor != null)
            pipeline.addLast("pipelineExecutor",
                             new ExecutionHandler(pipelineExecutor));
        pipeline.addLast("handler", controller.getChannelHandler(state));
        return pipeline;
    }

}
```

But in fact, as Floodlight gives null to the second argument of the constructor, the execution handler and executor object is never assigned to the pipeline.

```
...
final ServerBootstrap bootstrap = createServerBootStrap();

bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddr", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.sendBufferSize", Controller.SEND_BUFFER_SIZE);

ChannelPipelineFactory pfact = new OpenflowPipelineFactory(this, null);
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(pfact);
InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(openFlowPort);
final ChannelGroup cg = new DefaultChannelGroup();
cg.add(bootstrap.bind(sa));
...
```

My question is, 'what happens if there's no pipeline executor is set to the pipeline'? Any default pipeline executor is assumed? If it is, OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor executor is always assumed?

Thank you in advance, waiting for some help from the Netty and Floodlight specialists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no ExecutionHandler in the ChannelPipeline all events will be handled by the IO thread. If a ExecutionHandler is added the events are off-loaded to an extra Thread-Pool for the handlers after the ExecutionHandler. This allows blocking operations.

Comment: Thank you. But I'd like to give you one more question. In your answer, you mentioned 'IO thread', what IO thread you mean by the word?

Comment: Oh... never mind. I read [http://netty.io/3.6/guide/#start.7] and understood what did you mean by the 'IO thread'. It was a great help. Thank you!